# Installing Ember.js on MacOS

Tags: ember.js

I have tried to install Ember.js through npm, but it throws an error.

*npm install -g ember-cli*

Is there a way to do it without Homebrew ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I just figured out how to make it...**

You need to run this command:

```
*sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules*
```

then, the system will allow you to intsall ember globally.

More information you can find here:
*https://flaviocopes.com/npm-fix-missing-write-access-error/*

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#about) for installing Node and NPM. It makes installing new versions of node much easier and doesn't require `sudo` to install and manage other NPM packages.